# How to Show Message Box for specific User

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to solve an issue with showing Message Boxes/Alerts for a specific User. My application starts with Windows and it interacts with multiple Windows users for the whole time(1 or more users can be logged in the same time). When the user logs in and performs certain operations, app should display Message Box/Alert Dialog for this user only. My question is: how to display/show dialog for this user only?

Comment: What do you mean by "1 or more users can be logged in the same time"?  How are you achieving this in a winforms app?  Do you mean you may have multiple instances of the app running, each with a user logged in?

Comment: Your application shows message box on all computers at same time?

Comment: Very vague question. How do the users interact? Are they logged on via Remote Desktop?

Comment: When you call MessageBox.ShowDialog() are multiple users seeing it? If so, how many times is this line being called?

Comment: No, I have single computer and i have Single instance of the app. All logged on users have access to this app. All users are logged via Remote Desktop. 
I was trying to use Enviroment.Username and I am getting proper user but the problem is with showing msg for this user How can I catch user screen?

Comment: For the moment all other users are seeing it

Comment: Problem solved - Citrix was causing those this issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the current username to check if it's the username you want to Show the message box accordingly:

```
//..............
if(Environment.UserName == "yourUserName"){
   //Show message box here
}
//..............
```